# multiple duplicates in my query

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm having duplicate informations in my query.. I only need to accomplish is I have 1 textbox and whenever I type something it searches in the first name or last name but problem is whenever I type something in my textbox my query returns MULTIPLE DATA which is the problem because I only have 1 data of each record. What is wrong with this query. stuck for 2 days -_-

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

con.Open()
cmd = New MySqlCommand("SELECT tr.res_lname, tr.res_fname, tr.purok_name, tu.username, 

DATE_FORMAT(tv.transDate,'%M'), tv.status FROM tbl_violation AS tv 
INNER JOIN tbl_resident AS tr 
INNER JOIN tbl_user AS tu WHERE tr.res_id = tv.res_id 
AND tv.encodedbyId = tu.user_id AND tv.status = 0 
AND DATE_FORMAT(tv.transDate,'%M') <> DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%M') 
AND tr.res_lname like @lname OR tr.res_fname like @fname", con)

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", "%" & TextBox1.Text & "%")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", "%" & TextBox1.Text & "%")

dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        dgv.Rows.Clear()
        While dr.Read
            dgv.Rows.Add(dr(0), dr(1), dr(2), dr(3), dr(4), dr(5))
        End While

End Sub
```

Comment: what output you expect?

Comment: I need to see.. ex. I have a data named Lisa Roberts and Jake Berts.. if I typed 'Li' or 'Ro' on same textbox, I only need to see the record of Lisa Roberts

Comment: Could you please also post the structures of the tables, and the relationship between them?

Comment: I dont understand why you have just one textbox. You should have 2 different textboxes

Comment: I want a search box that can search any first name or last name with only one textbox.

Comment: In your case if you type Li or Ro it should only return Lisa Roberts and not Jake berts

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to do.

Comment: so what are you getting now when you type Li or Ro?

Comment: what happens if first name is stored as Jack Dawson and lastName is stored is Dawood. now you type Daw? so what will you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current query posted in question have a potential problem. I'm not sure if this is the main problem that cause your query return more data then you expect.

```
.....
WHERE 
    tr.res_id = tv.res_id 
        AND tv.encodedbyId = tu.user_id 
        AND tv.status = 0 
        AND DATE_FORMAT(tv.transDate,'%M') <> DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%M') 
        AND tr.res_lname like @lname OR tr.res_fname like @fname
```

the query above will return all rows that satisfy condition `tr.res_fname like @fname` ignoring other filters in the WHERE clause. I guess you want this instead

```
.....
WHERE 
    tr.res_id = tv.res_id 
        AND tv.encodedbyId = tu.user_id 
        AND tv.status = 0 
        AND DATE_FORMAT(tv.transDate,'%M') <> DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%M') 
        AND (tr.res_lname like @lname OR tr.res_fname like @fname)
```

Comment: Thank you, you sir just saved me hours. that is what I am looking.

Comment: what is difference between first and second query?

Comment: notice parentheses in this part : `(tr.res_lname like @lname OR tr.res_fname like @fname)`